# Transferring Array List from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

i have some question. i have function that creating list from database

```
public List<Langganan> getlistLanggananID(String kode){
    System.out.println(kode);
    List<Langganan> tokoList = new ArrayList();
    try {
       String sql = "SELECT idms_langganan, nama_langganan, alamat, kota FROM ms_langganan WHERE idms_langganan = " + "'" + kode + "'";
       Connection conn = datman.logOn();
       Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
       /* get result from list */
       while (rs.next()){
          Langganan lg = new Langganan();
          lg.setKodelangganan(rs.getString("idms_langganan"));
          lg.setNama(rs.getString("nama_langganan"));
          lg.setAlamat(rs.getString("alamat"));
          lg.setKota(rs.getString("kota"));
          tokoList.add(lg);
       }
    } catch (Exception se) {
        Logger.getLogger(MasterLangganan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, se);
        java.lang.System.out.println("Error on Function MasterLangganan Show List: " + se.toString());   
    }
    return tokoList;

}
```

it return list based on specific ID --> kode

then i execute the function through servlet

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
       String kode = request.getParameter("kode");
       MasterLangganan ml = new MasterLangganan();
       ml.getlistLanggananID(kode);
        /* sending list to JSP page */
        request.setAttribute("listlangganan",ml.getlistLanggananID(kode));
    } catch(Exception es){
        Logger.getLogger(setSettings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, es);
    }finally {            
       java.lang.System.out.println("setSettings Servlet has been executed");
    }
}
```

but how to sending the result from servlet to jsp page? because what i got just only error on my jsp page

here's the JSP page

```
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Tambah Langganan</h3>
 </div>
     <%
          MasterLangganan ml = new MasterLangganan();
          ml.getlistLanggananID("000");
     %>
  <div class="panel-body">
     <form name="system_settings" method="POST" action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/setDataLangganan">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <p>Nama</p> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_langganan" readonly="readonly" id="nama_langganan" value="<% ((Langganan)request.getAttribute("listlangganan")).getNama(); %>">
          <p>Alamat</p>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alamat" readonly="readonly" id="alamat" value="<% ((Langganan)request.getAttribute("listlangganan")).getAlamat(); %>">
          <p>Kota</p>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kota" readonly="readonly" id="kota" value="<% ((Langganan)request.getAttribute("listlangganan")).getKota(); %>">
          <p>Sales Area</p>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="salesarea" readonly="readonly" id="salesarea" value="<% ((Langganan)request.getAttribute("listlangganan")).getSalesArea(); %>">
</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Actions</p>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Edit" name="edit" id="edit">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Cancel" name="cancel" id="cancel">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Save" name="save" id="submit" style="display: none;" >
 </div>
</form>
```

i just need to place the List in the textfield so it can be editable.

how proper way to do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.jsp.system.langganan_jsp._jspService(langganan_jsp.java:205)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)

Comment: Btw, you'd have to use `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>` to populate the JSP (or aquire the outputstream and write to it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

> Transferring Array List from Servlet to JSP

You need to forward to JSP page

```
request.setAttribute("listlangganan",ml.getlistLanggananID(kode));
request.getRequestDispatcher("MyJSP.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

At `MyJSP.jsp`

```
 <c:forEach items="${listlangganan}" var="item">

  <!--Here populate the data to table or div-->    
 </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

`String kode = request.getParameter("kode");` In your post you have mentioned kode is an id so `request.getParameter("kode");`  will not work
to make it work do a hidden field like this way

```
<input type ="hidden" name="kode" value="<%=values you want to pass%>"> and submit this hidden field along with the form.Then only you can receive using `request.getParameter()`
```

Comment: i have place some static kode for this, just for testing purpose.. ml.getlistLanggananID("000"); but the problem i think is not there.

Comment: @randytan I answered as per your post,you wrote id kode there in your post.